# How can I redirect to js component and send information to db via php upon clicking submit?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

Upon clicking `submit`, I'm getting redirected to `Home.js` with no problems but no information isn't being sent to the db.

However, if I do get rid of the redirection, then the data gets sent to the db with no problems but it won't re-direct me to `Home.js`.  Instead, it redirects me to `demo.php`

**Goal**:  How can I successfully get redirected to `Home.js` (which I am right now) and send data to the db simultaneously?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from "./Home";

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redirect: false
        };
        this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    }

    nextPage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({redirect: true});
    }

    render() {
        const go = this.state.redirect;

        if(go) return <Home/>;

        return (
            <div>
                <form action="http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php" onSubmit={(e) => this.nextPage(e)} method={"POST"} encType="multipart/form-data">

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Email</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" name="username"/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="password" name="password"/>
                    </div>

                    <button className="btn btn-primary" value="Login" name={"submit"}>Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Here's `demo.php`:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginapp");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) ";
    $query .= " VALUES('$username', '$password')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
        echo "Data send successfully to SQL";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending data using Javascript  or php ? I mean m just curious to see how you are transferring the data. I dont have any knowledge on php.

Comment: @PranayTripathi using JS to send data to php

Comment: have you tried adding a timeout to setState after 5 secs, it may fix the issue. I think when your submit is called, it get replaced very soon by `setState` or you can use that it cant get registered

Comment: try removing `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @PranayTripathi I tried that way before, it doesn't work

Comment: does your `onSubmit` automatically call the php code if you remove `(e) => this.nextPage(e)` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `e.preventDefault()`, you are instructing the browser not to automatically send the form data. Instead, you have to perform that task yourself.

Inside the `nextPage(e)` method, you should be grabbing the form data and performing an ajax POST request to your server. You should probably be using the component state to store any user input.

Here's one way you could do it.

```
export default class FormComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    surname: ""
  };

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("json", JSON.stringify(this.state));

    fetch("http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="post">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            name="name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="surname">Surname</label>
          <input
            name="surname"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.surname}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ surname: e.target.value })}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={e => this.submitForm(e)}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: oh ok, I see what you're saying.  May you please show me an example of such scenario?  I think I get what you're referring to but I still not quite sure.  Are you talking about something like `fetch(...) ...`?

Comment: Yes using fetch is one way to do it. Updated answer with a full example.

Comment: sincerely appreciate this, but I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to explain what doesn't work. If you open your dev tools, you should be seeing a POST request to your server. If the issue is server side, you may set a breakpoint to better understand what's going on.

Comment: my apologies, yes I do see a post request in my devs tools (network tab) with the form data I entered but it's not being sent to the db and it's not redirecting me to Home.js